# No password in magmi?

Tags: magmi

I just setup Magmi, wanting to use it for making importing stuff easier. However, I was pretty dazzled when I visited magento magmi/web/magmi.php and realized I didn't ask for any login credentials.

Can someone please explain me how this can be safe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using `htpassword`. It's probably the easiest way.
You can generate the files here: http://www.web2generators.com/apache-tools/htpasswd-generator

Place the generated `.htpassword` outside of the public site directory (so one up from where you installed Magento) and in your Magmi folder place a `.htaccess` file with the following content

```
AuthUserFile /home/website/.htpasswd <-- or whatever path
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My restricted Area"
Require valid-user
```

Comment: Thanks! But is it seriously not supposed to be password protected by default?

Comment: @user2806026 nope, not that I know of. You'd be amazed how many shops have magmi exposed

Comment: I've just installed magmi 0.7.22 and have been asked for a username and password.